# Typescript class method returns undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a typescript class, and i have two functions inside it, which are supposed to compute the ratio of likes and dislikes.

```
    export class MyClass {
        thumbedUp?: number;
        thumbedDown?: number;
    
        likePercent?= () => Math.round((this.thumbedUp / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);
        dislikePercent?= () => Math.round((this.thumbedDown / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);

}
```

but when i create a MyClass instance like `myClass:MyClass = {thumbedUp: 10, thumbedDown: 12};` and i try to call myClass.likePercent, it returns undefined. I really don't understand why as my object is instanciated... Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: 1) Your "instance" is not an instance. You need to `new MyClass` 2) It does not make much sense to have `likePercent` and `dislikePercent` to be "optional" 3) what do you want to do when `thumbedUp` and/or `thumbedDown` is undefined?

Comment: For more detail: `const myClass:MyClass = {thumbedUp: 10, thumbedDown: 12};` tells the compiler that `myClass` is a variable of type `MyClass`. The problem is that assign it an object that just happens to "look like" the class properties. But it is not an `instanceof MyClass` and would not have any prototype functions from the class.

Comment: Hello, and thank you for your answer. I made these properties optional just for testing purpose, i will remove it ^^

Comment: I think you need a crash course in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

```
export class MyClass {
        thumbedUp: number;
        thumbedDown: number;
  constructor(thumbedUp:number, thumbedDown:number ){
      this.thumbedDown=thumbedUp;
      this.thumbedUp=thumbedDown;
  }

 likePercent():number{

return Math.round((this.thumbedUp / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);;
 }
    
dislikePercent():number{
return Math.round((this.thumbedDown / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);
}
}
 



var myclass = new MyClass(10,12);
console.log(myclass.likePercent())
```

Answer (score -1):

do like me

```
 export class MyClass {
        thumbedUp: number;
        thumbedDown: number;
  constructor(){
      this.thumbedDown=0;
      this.thumbedUp=0;
  }

 likePercent():number{

return Math.round((this.thumbedUp / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);;
 }
    
dislikePercent():number{
return Math.round((this.thumbedDown / (this.thumbedDown + this.thumbedUp)) * 100);
}
     
    

}
```

Comment: use undefined opr when receive response not for that